# Java 8 streams reduce and combine List items to Map

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream, reduce

I need to create map with keys of name1/2 summing values value1/2.

What could be the cleanest way to rewrite this using java 8 streams?

```
class Item {

    private String name1;
    private Integer value1;
    private String name2;
    private Integer value2;

    public Item(final String name1, final Integer value1, final String name2, final Integer value2) {
        this.name1 = name1;
        this.value1 = value1;
        this.name2 = name2;
        this.value2 = value2;
    }
    //getters and setters
}
```

```
List<Item> list = Lists.newArrayList(
                new Item("aaa", 1, "bbb", 2),
                new Item("bbb", 5, "ccc", 3),
                new Item("aaa", 8, "bbb", 7),
                new Item("bbb", 2, "aaa", 5));

Map<String, Integer> map = Maps.newHashMap();

for (Item item : list) {
    map.merge(item.name1, item.value1, Integer::sum);
    map.merge(item.name2, item.value2, Integer::sum);
}

System.out.println(map);//{aaa=14, ccc=3, bbb=16}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A possible solution is to flat map each item into a stream made by two entries: each entry will be composed of the name and the corresponding value. Then, this is collected into a map by summing the values of the values having the same key. Since there is no built-in pair to hold both values, we can use `AbstractMap.SimpleEntry`.

```
Map<String, Integer> map =
    list.stream()
        .flatMap(i -> Stream.of(new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(i.name1, i.value1), new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(i.name2, i.value2)))
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue, Integer::sum));
```

Alternatively, it might be simpler to just use a custom `collect` call. The accumulator merges each key, just like what you have in the `for` loop body. The tricky part is the combiner, which in this case merges two maps together by iterating over the entries of the second map and merging them into the first one.

```
Map<String, Integer> map =
        list.stream()
            .collect(
                HashMap::new,
                (m, i) -> {
                    m.merge(i.name1, i.value1, Integer::sum);
                    m.merge(i.name2, i.value2, Integer::sum);
                },
                (m1, m2) -> m2.forEach((k, v) -> m1.merge(k, v, Integer::sum))
            );
```

Comment: I'm asking just for curiosity. Why are you using `reduce` instead of `collect`? Are there any advantages?

Comment: @Flown No it's really the same. The `flatMap` call is not that straight-forward because of the necessity to have a tuple holder (so might be harder to understand). `reduce` is just an alternative solution that reads more like the `for` loop. There may be a difference in performance though if the list is quite large, not sure.

Comment: The question was targeting your second approach and I found an answer in the Oracle tutorials. `reduce` is used in an immutable and `collect` mutable reduction. In sequential execution both reductions show the same behaviour. If you want to use parallelized `Stream` it would be better to use `collect`: `list.stream().collect(HashMap::new, (m, i) -> {m.merge(i.name1, i.value1, Integer::sum); m.merge(i.name2, i.value2, Integer::sum);}, (m1, m2) -> m1.forEach((k, v) -> m2.merge(k, v, Integer::sum)))`

Comment: It seems that order matters in the `combiner` function. So it should look like: `(m1, m2) -> m2.forEach((k, v) -> m1.merge(k, v, Integer::sum))`